# How to insert/ update xml data in Mongodb with xml2js library

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to understand the logic of how to import XML in MongoDB. I'd like to do this with JavaScript and xml2js library. Are there any good examples?

**Steps:**

1. Download xml to folder from XML feed
2. Check whether data exists in MongoDB. If it does not, insert in collection.
3. If data exists in the collection, check whether there is a change and if there are changes, update the document in collection.

We are talking about sports scores, so XML changes depending on the game.

**Example of XML:**

```
<livescore updated="20.09.2016 09:44:23" sport="soccer">
<league country="argentina" name="Argentina: Primera Division" cup="False" id="2914" sub_id="29144">
<match alternate_id="4349375" alternate_id_2="4552948" commentary="True" date="20.09.2016" id="4466495" static_id="20091623378212337749" status="FT" time="00:15">
<home goals="0" id="2337821" name="Gimnasia L.P." />
<away goals="1" id="2337749" name="Atl. Rafaela" />
<events>
<event assist="" assistid="" extra_min="" id="24542984" minute="9" player="E. Medaglia" playerid="2612790" result="" team="away" type="yellowcard" />
<event assist="" assistid="" extra_min="" id="24542985" minute="21" player="D. Imperiale" playerid="2580829" result="" team="home" type="yellowcard" />
<event assist="F. Luna" assistid="305493" extra_min="" id="24542986" minute="57" player="M. Bognino" playerid="2778704" result="[0 - 1]" team="away" type="goal" />
<event assist="" assistid="" extra_min="" id="24542987" minute="75" player="S. Paz" playerid="2766117" result="" team="away" type="yellowcard" />
<event assist="" assistid="" extra_min="" id="24542988" minute="87" player="D. Imperiale" playerid="2580829" result="" team="home" type="yellowred" />
</events>
<ht score="[0-0]" />
<ft score="[0-1]" />
</match>
</league>
</livescore>
```